# Can I create a function with the same name as the class?

Tags: c#

I want to create a function with the same name as its class using C#.

Sample Snippet:

```
public class MyCustomer
{
    public MyCustomer()
    {
    }

    public void MyCustomer()
    {
    }
}
```

If I try to compile it visual studio is throwing an error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You may wish to review [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this handy guide on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  I've edited some inappropriate stuff out of your question, and added some [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  **Could you tell us what specific error this code is generating, please?**

Comment: Why do you **need** to? Can't you call it something similar but not the same? Using the same name as the class is reserved for constructors.

Comment: You cannot use the declared class name as one of its members.

Comment: Please rename the question. All questions could have this title; it is not helping others.

Comment: Do you really want to write code like `MyCustomer myCustomer = new MyCustomer(); myCustomer.MyCustomer();` ?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot create a function that is the same name as the class name. A function with the same name as the class name is reserved for constructors.

Answer (score 3):

A function with same name as class name is known as Constructor. It gets executed when the object is created. You can have multiple constructors (constructor overloading), but in that case, you will have constructors with different set of parameters. For example:

```
public MyCustomer()
{}

public MyCustomer(int x)
{
  // use the x variable.
}
```

Another important point is constructors have no return type.

Comment: Years later, but you can't specify even a `void` as a return type for a constructor. You must use `public MyCustomer(int x)`.

Comment: @Andrew yes you are right.. it was a copy paste issue which I over looked. Thanks for correcting.. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't have method name `void MyCustomer()` that is same as class name - it's reserved for the constructor `public MyCustomer()`

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can't do that. Just for the sake of clarity though, the language specification reference (using the C# 4 spec) is section 10.3 (emphasis mine):

> Instance constructors, destructors and static constructors must have the same name as the immediately enclosing class. **All other members must have names that differ from the name of the immediately enclosing class.**

So you *could* create a nested class with a method with the same name as the enclosing class:

```
public class MyCustomer
{
    public class Nested
    {
        public void MyCustomer() {}
    }
}
```

... but I'd *strongly* recommend that you don't do so.

Could you tell us *why* you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to translate from .net VB. In VB it is allow to have a sub or Function with the same name of the class, since the constructor is called New(). BTW, one of the reason I do not appreciate VB.

Comment: @AlexAlvarez: I'm actually surprised that's allowed by IL, but it is. (I guess that's because the constructor is called `.ctor`.) There's no way of getting around the rule in C# though.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the function. Seriously a function name should indicate the effect of the method.

So change it to ShowCustomerDetails or CreateMyCustomer or...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a function name the same as the class name.  This is reserved for constructors

Answer (score 1):

Simply say you can not create it , what you want. I think you need to read about constructors.
The class name is considered as reserved keyword for that class only, and allows to user for constructor name only. where as framework does not allow you to use it with void / any return type for method name.

Comment: Yes I agree with @lalit. this is perfect explanation i think.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could change something minor like the casing, altho that in particular could break naming conventions.

Assuming you want an exact match, you can't write this directly. As others have pointed out, the class name is used to declare constructors. However, there are indirect means.

With a liberal reading of the question, probably the best way to write a method with the same name as the class is to use an extension method:

```
public class MyCustomer
{
    public MyCustomer()
    { /* constructor */ }

    public void SameNameHack()
    { /* method */ }
}

public static class MyCustomerExtension
{
    public static void MyCustomer(this MyCustomer self)
        => self.SameNameHack();
}
```

The extension method isn't technically part of the class, but it does allow you to call `.MyCustomer()` on a variable of type `MyCustomer`, exactly as you would otherwise, which may be all you really need.

You can also accomplish this in a different kind of way thru a separate interface. This trick also works for properties:

```
public interface IMethodHack
{
    void MyCustomer();
}

public interface IPropertyHack
{
    MyCustomer MyCustomer { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomer : IMethodHack, IPropertyHack
{
    public MyCustomer()
    { /* constructor */ }

    void IMethodHack.MyCustomer()
    { /* method */ }

    MyCustomer IPropertyHack.MyCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is referencing it. Given variables of type `MyCustomer`, you wouldn't be able to call `.MyCustomer()` or access `.MyCustomer` directly, you would have to cast first:

```
((IMethodHack)customer1).MyCustomer();

IMethodHack hack = customer2;
hack.MyCustomer();
```

and similarly for the property. So this option may not be that useful.